# Storing OAuth tokens in Node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth, jwt

I'm developing an application where the user logs into their [Reddit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit) account and the refresh token obtained from Reddit would be used later to keep the user logged in. To store the refresh token, I have tried using the session variables, and it uses cookies on the client side which I find icky. I wanted to use JWTs to store the token in the payload, but I then found out the payload itself isn't encrypted.

What are some methods I could use to store this token securely to be used later?

Comment: Refresh Token should be stored safely (should not be part of the data that is exchanged between the client and server). [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14166117/174184) could give you some tips.

Comment: @TJ- What I'm currently doing is using connect-mongo to store the refresh key in the user's session. Is there a better way of doing this?